# Use List.foreach to write the equivalent of this for loop

Tags: scala

I have this code snippet:

```
val ln = List (1, 2, 3)

for (i <- ln){
  println(i*2)
  }
```

Is it possible to write the same code but using the `List.foreach` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ln.foreach(i => println(i*2))
```